# Проблема с пунктуацией?

Tags: пунктуация, сравнение

«...И который я пытаюсь вернуть себе как Пиковая Дама проигранное богатство».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запятая отделяет придаточное предложение. Только вот с предложением не все ясно. Что именно пытается вернуть автор?

Comment: Спасибо. Полное предложение: "Я стремлюсь сменить слабость своего пера на силу моего конструкторского карандаша, с которым пытаются соревноваться автокады и который я пытаюсь вернуть себе, как Пиковая Дама проигранное богатство".

Comment: Нет. Придаточное здесь скорее всего кончается точкой. Не морочоьте людям голову.

Comment: ответ Аленке.Я стремлюсь сменить ... - главное предложение. "союз же и" обединяет два придаточных, которые заканчивается на месте запятой. Ср.: вернуть так, как Пиковая Дама(возвратила) проигранное богатство". это неполное придаточное.

Comment: Вы можете отвечать кому угодно, но старайтесь все-таки не городить ерунды.

Comment: behemothus, Вы не правы. "Как Пиковая Дама проигранное богатство" -- неполное придаточное предложение, а не сравнительный оборот. См. http://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/743-231_pridatochnye_sravnitelnye.html : _В сравнительном придаточном допускается пропуск сказуемого – оно уже названо в главном предложении..._

Comment: Серж, это сравнительный оборот. И не надо опраувдываться подобным образом. Если Вы можете объяснить, почему это не сравнительный оборот - милости прошу. Но давать ссылки на источники, где нет подобных утверждений, не стоит. Почитайте лучше русскую грамматику.

Comment: А вообще, зачем искать окольных путей с пропущенным сказеемым, , если есть простое понимание того, что такое все равно ведь формулировка "закрывает придаточного не верна". Чем бы последний кусок текста ни был,  он относится к ***придаточному***,  "который я стараюсь...", следовательно запятая ***не может его "закрывать"***. Его "закрывает" точка.

Comment: _behemothus: формулировка "закрывает придаточного не верна"._ === Так ведь в ответе-то у Сержа не "**закрывает** придаточное", а "**отделяет** придаточное", идущее после этой запятой.

Comment: Ээээ...  Ну да, это я ошибся формально, не точно процитировал. Но разве есть разница? отделять - это я бы еще понял в отношении однородных членов, но тут-то (если вашей версии придерживаться) придаточные разного уровня. Дело-то не в слове, а в структуре предложения. Или у вас по вашей грамматике оно тоже непосредственно к главному относится?

Comment: И вообще, slava1947, можете показать, где в вашем источнике говориться, что это ***не сравнительный оборот***? Мало того, что источник сомнительной авторитетности, так там масса всяких сведений, но непонятно, почему это не сравнительный оборот?

Comment: Для придаточного _"как Пиковая Дама проигранное богатство"_ **главным** является предложение _"который я пытаюсь вернуть себе"_. И запятая действительно **отделяет** придаточное с Дамой от этого главного.

Comment: behemothus, я могу сослаться на учебник Литниевской, но Вы опять будете настаивать на своем.

Comment: _behemothus: непонятно, почему это не сравнительный оборот_… === Потому что в этом "обороте" есть слово _**богатство**_, не образующее словосочетания с Пиковой Дамой. Сочетается оно с опущенным сказуемым, восстанавливаемым из главного (для этого придаточного) предложения: _"который я **пытаюсь вернуть** себе, как Пиковая Дама (**пыталась вернуть**) проигранное богатство"_.

Comment: @slava1947, я не вижу здесь пропущенного сказуемого.  Во всяком случае такого очевидного, как Вам всем хочется. Возможно потому, что у Пушкина ничего такого и в помине нет. Давайте наоборот. Если Вы явным образом покажете, что грамматика сравнительного оборота здесь невозможна, я соглашусь. Только не вставайте в позу Сержа, который тыкает в утверждение, что "Икс ***может быть*** Игреком", и на этом основании выводит неучем всякого, кто думает, что "Икс ***может быть*** еще Зетом".

Comment: *- могу сослаться на учебник Литниевской,* - если Вы заранее знаете, что я буду делать, значит не можете сослаться. Серж, мне наплевать на что Вы ссылаетесь. Я вообще не признаю авторитарных догматиков. Но если вы ссылаетесь на формулировки, которые не относятся к обсуждаемому вопросу, то я, естественно, их игнорирую. А вы регулярно подсовываете мне источники по принципу "в огороде бузина, а в Киеве - дядька".

Comment: Так ваша проблема в том и заключается, что вы считаете себя высшей инстанцией  и глубоко уверены,что ваши ответы не подлежат оспариванию. Смешно!  Поэтому и мне наплевать на ваше мнение.

Comment: _behemothus: Давайте наоборот. Если Вы явным образом покажете, что грамматика сравнительного оборота здесь невозможна, я соглашусь_. === 

См. http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/lingvistic/1585/%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9:

_В состав сравнительного оборота обычно входит:
 а) имя существительное в именительном падеже, без пояснительных слов или с пояснительными словами — согласованным либо несогласованным определением…_  Думаю, согласитесь с тем, что "проигранное богатство" не является **определением** к Пиковой Даме.

Comment: Различать сравнительный оборот и придаточное сравнительное следует,  прежде всего, ГРАММАТИЧЕСКИ (не стоит думать, что это можно сделать по какому-то особому смыслу, который имел в виду или не имел в виду, к примеру, Пушкин). Сравнительный оборот - это сравнение предмета, признака, действия с другим предметом, признаком, действием). Неполное сравнительное придаточное - это сравнение    СИТУАЦИЙ, например: Он бросился бежать, как заяц (сравнительный оборот). Он бросился бежать, как заяц от волка (неполное сравнительное придаточное).

Comment: Добрые люди бросались на него, как собаки на медведя (классический вариант неполного придаточного предложения).

Answer (score 2):

Запятая ставится:

...и который я пытаюсь вернуть себе, как Пиковая Дама (пыталась вернуть) проигранное богатство.

Неполное сравнительное придаточное (с пропущенным сказуемым) относится к  определительному придаточному предложению, последовательное подчинение предложений.

Answer (score 0):

Alenka, тут с грамматикой все ясно на самом деле. Серж опять в дебри ударился.

"Как Пиковая Дама проигранное богатство" - ***сравнительный оборот в составе придаточного***. Это было ясно и без контекста, хотя в чем я с Сержем могу согласиться, фразу надо приводить полностью, иначе часто возникают сомнения.

Тут другое. Не помню, чтобы Пиковая Дама (пушкинская), что-то такое пыталась сделать в плане возвращения себе богатства. Ваш автор с карандашом точно читал Пушкина?

//=============

Поскольку уже третий человек настаивает на неполном сравнительном, то вынужден объясниться. Весь разговор, видимо, крутится из-за неверного понимания смысла. 
Я не вижу здесь однозначной интерпретации типа:
*как Пиковая Дама (пыталась вернуть) проигранное богатство*
В таких случаях естественно выбрать более простой вариант. Сравнительный оборот, придаточным не являющийся.

Впрочем, это на запятую никак не влияет. Поэтому усиленное противопоставление одного другому вистов не добавляет.

Comment: Да, похоже на то... Он, может, Германа имел ввиду...

Comment: Ну вот, а Серж обиделся. ))) А на что похоже? (+) Добавлено: Так и Германн в том замечен не был

Comment: . Alenka, Германн - это фамилия. С двумя Н пишется.)))

Comment: Буду знать. Пристыдили. Очень давно читала.

Comment: Да ладно Вам. Этого многие не знают. Вот меня стыдят со сравнительным оборотом - это хуже. Собственно, я ведь и не заостряю на этом... Что оборот, что придаточное, запятая ставится по тем же мотивам. А вот почему у вас-то возникло сомнение?

Comment: Потому что я этого правила все равно до конца не понимаю... И потому что с детства осталось впечатление, что запятая перед **как** ставится всегда, и теперь, как только я вижу сравнительный оборот - возникает страх...

Comment: Аааа... Так вым стоило это в формулировке вопроса уточнить, а то занесло в такие дебри... Alenka, когда сравнительный (оборот ли, придаточное ли) страха быть не должно. Там запятая всегда. Вот когда не сравнительный... Но по сути актуален только один спорный случай, когда запятой перед "как" не должно быть.  Обстоятельство образа действия. http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183 Со всеми остальными запутаться очень трудно.

Comment: _behemothus: Весь разговор, видимо, крутится из-за неверного понимания смысла._ === Ну так в исходном-то предложении -- _"Я стремлюсь сменить слабость своего пера на силу моего конструкторского карандаша, с которым пытаются соревноваться автокады и который я пытаюсь вернуть себе, как Пиковая Дама проигранное богатство"_ -- смысл-то вряд ли кто обнаружит. Ну, кроме автора сего шедевра…

Comment: Так и я о том. ))) Но только вы однозначно считаете, что там пропущено именно то, что вы написали, а у меня при всей фееричной нелепости фразы, грамматика другая получается. Это тупик, видимо. Разбирать нелепицу на предмет грамматики не получится, а если и получится, то к единому мнению не придем.